# I'm Confused with Memcache vs Memcached vs php5-memcache

Tags: php, nginx, memcached, ubuntu-12.04

I followed the instruction in this [tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-nginx-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p4) on how to install nginx, php, and mysql including the php5-memcache.

I'm wondering if I still need to install the memcache or memcached without the "php5" prefix .

As of now my WordPress site is complaining the ff:

```
The following memcached servers are not responding or not running:

Page Cache: 127.0.0.1:11211.
Database Cache: 127.0.0.1:11211.
Object Cache: 127.0.0.1:11211.
This message will automatically disappear once the issue is resolved.
```

If it is needed to be installed, will it not conflict with php5-memcache? Or something like an overkill usage of the two version?

And what is the best version to use? Memcache or Memcached? php5-memcache or php5-memcached.

I heard that memcached with "d" is just a service or daemon. But somebody is trying to compare the two as what I have seen [here](http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2013/03/memcache-vs-memcached-php-benchmark/).

Answer (score 5):

The names of these extensions are confusing.

Actually, both php5-memcache and php5-memcached are PHP extensions for working with the memcached service ([Memcached server](http://memcached.org/)). They both give your PHP processes, the ability to be clients to the memcached service, i.e. to connect to memcached over the network, and to speak the memcached protocol, in order to use the memcached API.

The **php5-memcached extension is more stable and has more features** in my opinion, so I would suggest, that it should be tried first. Most of its operations are [faster](http://www.pozdravi.net/tmp/benchmark____php5-memcache___vs___php5-memcached____.php.results.html) too ([php source for the benchmark that produced these results](http://www.pozdravi.net/tmp/benchmark____php5-memcache___vs___php5-memcached____.php.txt)).

You still do need the actual **memcached** service started somewhere, and its address, in order to connect to it. The memcached service may be started on the same host, or on another host/hosts, if you want a *distributed* cache.

Answer (score 1):

memcache and memcached are 2 different servers, each has some features and stuff, you can read the differences as there's so many previous questions about that [check google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=memcache%20vs%20memcached) 
The ones starting with php are the extentions used to access the service, just like to use mysql you need php5-mysql, and to use curl you need php5-curl.

<s>So you have php5-memcache for memcache, and php5-memcached for memcached, you can read about what each provide from those links: 
 [memcached lib](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) and [memcahe lib](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)</s>

**EDIT:** Just want to correct the wrong info I wrote above, both `php5-memcache` and `php5-memcached` connect to the [`memcached`](http://memcached.org) server, they are just different extensions for the same server, I guess just like `php5-mysql` vs `php5-mysqli`

You can still use both together, there's no conflict, but i believe you only need one not both, because most features are available with both, some provide little more features, another candidate service is `redis`, you should read into that too, it has some features not available in the memcached servers.

Comment: Thanks. I also installed pecl memcache and when I uninstalled it I got an error in my drupal site `You must enable the PECL memcached or memcache extension to use memcache.inc`. How can I restore my previous config before I install pecl? I think pecl mess up my configuration.

Comment: do you have memcache or memcached installed after u uninstalled it ? try `dpgk -l | grep memcache`, if you don't get any thing or you get only the ones starting with `php5-` then just install memcached using `apt-get` it's good enough

Comment: I am not aware of a service called memcache . There are memcached and memcachedb (which is protocol compatible with memcached, but provides persistance).

Comment: Ok I looked around and apparently you're right, `php5-memcahche` and `php5-memcached` are both extension to connect to the `memcached` server, sorry my bad.
anyway, as far as I know the `php5-memcached` provide more instructions and functionality than the `php5-memcache` provides