# trouble with yii PHP 'memcached' installation. error: "requires PHP 'memcached' extension to be loaded"

Tags: php, caching, yii, memcached, wamp

I am trying to run a website on my localhost. PHP Version 5.5.12 wamp 64 bit windows 8.1.

The website is built with Yii 1.1 framework.

I installed 'memcached' and 'memcache' extension successfully (i know it from the tests i made).

(fyi: i followed this guide https://commaster.net/content/installing-memcached-windows for the installation of 'memcached')

the problem is that even after i successfully installed 'memcached' extension, i still get this following error when i try to load my website on my localhost:
"... requires PHP 'memcached' extension to be loaded"

do anybody knows what is the problem? do i have to config the option in order to make it work?

FYI:
when i run this code:

```
<?php

$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");

$version = $memcache->getVersion();
echo "Server's version: ".$version."<br/>\n";

$tmp_object = new stdClass;
$tmp_object->str_attr = 'test';
$tmp_object->int_attr = 123;

$memcache->set('key', $tmp_object, false, 10) or die ("Failed to save data at the server");
echo "Store data in the cache (data will expire in 10 seconds)<br/>\n";

$get_result = $memcache->get('key');
echo "Data from the cache:<br/>\n";

var_dump($get_result);

?>
```

I GET:

```
Server's version: 1.4.4-14-g9c660c0
Store data in the cache (data will expire in 10 seconds)
Data from the cache:
C:\wamp\www\memtest2.php:19:
object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'str_attr' => string 'test' (length=4)
  public 'int_attr' => int 123
```

PLEASE HELP! MANY THANKS!

here is the Memcache from my phpinfo (if that will help)
[image]

Comment: in the output i don't see  "... requires PHP 'memcached' extension to be loaded"

Comment: i get this error when i try to browse my website. not this test code.

Comment: have you enabled memcache in php.ini load extension? have you checked phpinfo() ?

Comment: yes. i added the phpinfo printscreen to the question

Answer (score 0):

You have [php5's memcache extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.memcache.php) installed. You need the [memcache**d** extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.memcached.php). These are [two different extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21441943/428543). You can get the latest memcache**d** installation files from http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached

Comment: thanks for replying. i thought i installed both memcache and memcache*d*. anyway, i never got to this page http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached. how do i install it? does it work on windows wamp? cant seem to find a proper guide for this installation for wamp windows